# Leafletjs - Polylines not appearing where they should, Why?

Tags: leaflet, polyline

I have a map of London region, based on the bounds of the map area, I receive JSON consisting of start/end lat lngs which I then want to plot on the map. For this I'm using polylines and that works great, polylines are drawn and in perfect shape, but for some reason, it miniature in size as compared to the original size of the map. Please see image below for example, it is in perfect shape as that of the motorway lines (thick Blue lines) but smaller in size and in one corner. Can anyone advice what i'm doing wrong here ...

[image: Map With Problem plotting Polylines]

**Code**

```
$.each(content, function(titleName, titleValue) {
    startLat = (titleName === 'startLatitude')?titleValue:startLat;
    startLng = (titleName === 'startLongitude')?titleValue:startLng;
    endLat = (titleName === 'endLatitude')?titleValue:endLat;
    endLng = (titleName === 'endLongitude')?titleValue:endLng;
});

startLatLng = new L.LatLng(startLat, startLng);
endLatLng = new L.LatLng(endLat, endLng);

var pointList = [startLatLng, endLatLng];

var polyLine = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
    color: 'blue',
    opacity: 1,
    weight: 5
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle and post a link to it?

Comment: Hmmm... not sure how to do that as the data I'm getting is very dynamic and need a lot of data to create something similar :( ... what I'm thinking is that maybe the zoomLevels are different for the map and the drawn polylines, even thought I'm giving lat lngs, I thought it would plot without any hassle but seems like I was wrong ... :(

Answer (score -1):

Okay figured it out ... After long investigation, found that somehow css was not letting it grow to full size due to fixed width and height ... sorry for wasting all of your time ... Thanks for trying and helping though :)